# How to resolve the issue in RemoveAStud() not removing the node and crashes

Tags: c++, linked-list, crash, singly-linked-list

```
template<class theType>
newStudent<theType>* StudentList<theType>::getLocationOfID(const int & target, 
                                                           newStudent<theType> * theNext)
{
    newStudent<theType> * result = NULL;

    if(theNext != NULL)
    {   
        if (theNext->getID() == target)
            result = theNext;
        else
            result = getLocationOfID(target, theNext->getNext());
    }

    else
        return result;

} // end recursive getLocationOfID


template<class theType>
bool StudentList<theType>::RemoveAStudent() 
{

    newStudent<theType> * tmp = head, * prev = head, * curr = head;

    bool ableToRemove = true;

    int IDtoRemove;
    char answer;

    //no nodes
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "\n\t\t            No student transcript stored yet"
             << "\n\t\t     Please add the student list in order to remove" << endl;
        return !ableToRemove;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n\t\tWhich student ID would you like "
             << "to remove from the list? ";
        cin >> IDtoRemove;

        //remove the student located in the head
        if(head->getID() == IDtoRemove)
        {
            counter--;
            newStudent<theType> * tmp = head;
            head = getLocationOfID(IDtoRemove, head);
            delete tmp; //deletes in the head (first Node)

            cout << "\n\t\tThe Student Transcript belonging to ID " 
                 << IDtoRemove << " has been removed.";
            return ableToRemove;
        }

        else
        {
            newStudent<theType> * tmp = head, * prev = head, * curr = head;

            while(curr->getNext() != NULL && curr->getID() != IDtoRemove)
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = getLocationOfID(IDtoRemove, curr);
            }

            //removes in the middle
            if(curr->getNext() != NULL)
            {
                counter--;
                prev->setNext(curr->getNext());
                delete(curr); //delete anywhere in the middle

                cout << "\n\t\tThe Student Transcript belonging to ID " 
                     << IDtoRemove << " has been removed.";
                return ableToRemove;
            }

            else
            {   
                //remove at the end
                if(curr->getID() == IDtoRemove)
                {
                    counter--;
                    prev->setNext(NULL);
                    delete(curr); //removes last node

                    cout << "\n\t\tThe Student Transcript belonging to ID " 
                         << IDtoRemove << " has been removed.";
                    return ableToRemove;
                }

                else
                    cout << "\n\t\tThe ID " << IDtoRemove << " is not in the list.\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to remove a node from the list and crashes every time when i removed it and call the function print to print the remaining nodes in the list.

Please help me figure this out

Trying to remove a node from the list and crashes every time when i removed it and call the function print to print the remaining nodes in the list.

Please help me figure this out

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the only problem but I thin it's a problem that can explain a crash.

In this piece of code

```
        while(curr->getNext() != NULL && curr->getID() != IDtoRemove)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = getLocationOfID(IDtoRemove, curr);
        }
```

`getLocationOfID()` (if I'm not wrong) set `curr` to `NULL` id `IDtoRemove` isn't present in the list; in this case, `curr->getNext()` try to dereference a null pointer  ---> crash.

Are you sure that what you want isn't

```
        for ( curr = head ; curr && (curr->getID() != IDtoRemove) ; curr = curr->getNext() )
        {
            prev = curr;
        }
```

?

But, in this case, check (next) if `curr` is or isn't `NULL`, before dereferencing it.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

**--- EDIT ---**

I suspect that the use of `getLocationOfID()` in `RemoveAStudent()` is unusefull and dangerous.

The other point where you use it is

```
    if(head->getID() == IDtoRemove)
    {
        counter--;
        newStudent<theType> * tmp = head;
        head = getLocationOfID(IDtoRemove, head);
        delete tmp; //deletes in the head (first Node)
```

when you know that the node to remove is the head (`if`); so

```
        head = getLocationOfID(IDtoRemove, head);
```

is like

```
        head = head;
```

Your intention was

```
        head = head->getNext();
```

?

Otherwise you delete the `head` (`tmp == head`) and loose the following list.